# Keeping context when using jQuery.on

Tags: javascript, jquery, lodash

I'm using jQuery and lodash to build an interface, and I'm using delegated events like so:

```
function Interface() {
  this.connectEvents();
  _.bindAll(this);
};
_.extend(Interface.prototype, {
  connectEvents : function() {
    this.$clockNav.on('click', '.navprev a', this.previousTime);
  },
  previousTime : function() {
    this.getPreviousTime(this.currentTime);
  }
});
```

However, even though I've used `_.bindAll` to tie `previousTime` to the instance of the Interface object I'm controlling, jQuery overwrites that binding and instead sets `this` to be the element I've clicked on. How can I stop jQuery from doing this and preserve the correct value of `this`?

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use [$.proxy()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.proxy/) to pass a custom context to the event handler callback

```
Interface.prototype.connectEvents = function() {
  this.$clockNav.on('click', '.navprev a', $.proxy(this.previousTime, this));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [jQuery.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) or [Function.prototype.bind](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff841995%28v=vs.94%29.aspx) native method.

```
Interface.prototype.connectEvents = function() {
  this.$clockNav.on('click', '.navprev a', $.proxy(this.previousTime, this));
};
```

OR

```
Interface.prototype.connectEvents = function() {
  this.$clockNav.on('click', '.navprev a', this.previousTime.bind(this));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem proved much simpler than I thought: in my initialize function, I was calling `connectEvents` before `_.bindAll`. D'oh.

Answer (score 0):

There are a variety of ways to do this.  Another technique that hasn't already been mentioned is to use a local variable in the closure:

```
_.extend(Interface.prototype, {
  connectEvents : function() {
    var self = this;
    this.$clockNav.on('click', '.navprev a', function() {self.previousTime()});
  },
  previousTime : function() {
    var self = this;
    this.getPreviousTime(function() {self.currentTime()});
  }
});
```